# Append Query Command Button

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I have used a command button to append data to a table in the past just fine, however this time, when I try to

```
CurrentDb.Execute "APPEND_DailyAbsenceInput"
```

I get the error

> 3061: Too few parameters

I feel that this is linked to the fact that I am trying to get a date which has been entered within a textbox. The bizare thing is, If I double click the query in the navigation panel, everything works just fine, however the command button throws up this error.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `CDATE`, what is the SQL generated when the form is open.  Try not to use keywords, like `DATE` for your aliases etc.

Comment: Try `CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT …"`. Look at query object in SQL View to get syntax.